# Conroller name in url in codeigniter 4 is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNyBt.jpg)When I use this

```
Localhost/CI4/public
```

OR

```
Localhost/CI4/public/index.php
```

It loads and shows default page with default controller, but when I use

```
Localhost/CI4/public/index.php/Home
```

OR

```
Localhost/CI4/public/index.php/Home/index
```

It gives *`404 error File Not Found - Controller or its method is not found
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNyBt.jpg)

Routes. Php file
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfFPK.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If you have some code that is not working, you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing some code that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: Show us how you defined your routes in `Routes.php`

Comment: In addition, show us how you defined your default controller and method.

Comment: I have downloaded  codeigniter 4 
and  running with default settings and running it on my localhost without doing any change . When i incude controller name in url it doesn't work. Localhost/CI4/public/index.php is woking but.                                 Localhost/CI4/public/index.php/Home is not working

Comment: I am trying to run Home controller which comes with codeigniter 4 .

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your PHP code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: Run `php spark serve` rather than using localhost port 80.

Then open in browser http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

> Assume my controller name is `ContactController` and the method is `index`. And I'm accessing it with the URL `contact`

In config/route.php

```
$routes->get('contact', 'ContactController::index');
```

In Controller

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class ContactController extends BaseController
{
    public function index(): void
    {
        echo "call me";
    }
}
```

To access this just use

```
http://localhost/contact
```

Nothing to do with `public` or `index.php`

Comment: do i have to change $routes->get(); every time

Comment: i want to call method of controller then what i should do? without changing $routes->get();

Comment: Yes, you should. Not saying you can't do it. You must define the routes for security purposes and the application's health. Cz outsiders don't know what to click or type in URL. You've to define it

Comment: then in form_open() it will not work .there it will throw the same error

Comment: @DEVKumar did you remove the `index.php` append in the URL? Search for CI4 `.htaccess` will solve this

Answer (score 0):

**How to solve 404 pages** not found in **CodeIgniter 4**?
In your `app/config` folder the `Routs.php` file add the below line of code.

```php
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

[image: See below image for more details]